# Jquery not working for me

Tags: image

I have followed different solution here in stacj overflow with regards to coinslider not moving. So here's mine. It seems that I dont know how to make it move.
here's my code.

Thanks.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="LeavemanagementFinal.Index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>CrossXTrain - Home</title>
<link href="css/master.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/coin-slider-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
 <%--<style type="text/css">
.frame 
{
    font:12px arial;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:5;
  }
  </style>
 <script language="javascript">
  i = 0
  var speed = 1
  function scroll() {
     i = i + speed
    var div = document.getElementById("news")
    div.scrollTop = i
    if (i > div.scrollHeight - 160) { i = 0 }
    t1 = setTimeout("scroll()", 10)
  }
  </script>--%>

</head> 

<body onload="scroll()">
    <div class="divpage">
       <img src="images/header2.png">
         <div class="divmenu">
            <a class="FontStaticMenuItemStyle" href="index.aspx"> Home</a>
            <a class="FontStaticMenuItemStyle" href="leavemanagementlogin.aspx"> Leave Management</a>
            <a class="FontStaticMenuItemStyle" href="news.aspx"> News</a>
            <a class="FontStaticMenuItemStyle" href=""> Articles</a>
            <a class="FontStaticMenuItemStyle" href="aboutus.aspx"> About Us</a>
            <a class="FontStaticMenuItemStyle" href="contactus.aspx"> Contact Us</a>
         </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#news').news();
                });
            </script>
         <div class="mainbanner" id="news" >
            <img src="images/BUBLES.jpg" />
            <img src="images/CrossXtrain.jpg"/>
            <img src="images/CrossXtrain3.jpg"/>
            <img src="images/CrossXtrain4.jpg"/>
            <img src="images/CrossXtrain5.jpg"/>
            <img src="images/CrossXtrain6.jpg"/>
            <img src="images/CrossXtrain7.jpg"/>
            <img src="images/CrossXtrain8.jpg"/>
            <img src="images/CrossXtrain9.jpg"/>
         </div>
         <div class="clear">&nbsp</div>
         <div class="mainadfooter">
            <input type="image" class="secondinput" src="images/BUBLES.jpg"/>
            <input type="image" class="thirdinput" src="images/HCS.jpg" onclick="javascript: window.location.href = 'http://www.healthcaresynergy.com/'"/>
            <input type="image" class="thirdinput" src="images/fusionplus.png" onclick="javascript: window.location.href = 'http://sync.fusionpl.us//'"/>
            <input type="image" class="thirdinput" src="images/DoubleRule_Logo@2x.png" onclick="javascript: window.location.href = 'http://www.doublerule.com/'"/>
         </div>
         <div class="clear">&nbsp</div>
    </div>
         <div class="clear">&nbsp</div>
         <div class="footer"><p>Copyright © 2014. CrossXTrain Company Inc. All rights reserved. | Leave Management System - ISD (Php)</p></div>
</body>

 </html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#news').news();
        });
</script>
```

Thank you so much all.

Comment: Why do you use the script two times? What is `news()`?

Comment: I changed it this way but still no effect<script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#news').coinslider();
                    });
                </script>

Answer (score 1):

Your `script` needs to be inside the `html` tags.

Comment: I changed it this way but still no effect<script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#news').coinslider();
                    });
                </script>

Comment: is it executing? the console output would be helpful

Comment: How can i use that or how to use that one sir?

Comment: if you're using firefox, then you want to download the Firebug extension.  On Chrome, you can right-click and click on `inspect element`.  Either way then you want to click on the console tab and refresh the page.  It will show you if there is a bug in your JS.
http://getfirebug.com/